# Explanation about def rewind(f): f.seek(0)

Tags: python, function, seek, rewind

i was reading a book and there was a code which had a this line in it

```
def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)
```

and this is a line that i can't understand
can you please explain me what is going on ?

```
 from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)

print " first lets print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

print "now lets rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

print "lets print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_l, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

-im using python 2.7

thanks for your time

Comment: `rewind(current_file)`: your rewind function is used. removing it makes your code non-working.

Comment: Did you look up the documention for `seek`? That should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: What output did you get without the `rewind()`.  What were you expecting?  It definitely doesn't do nothing...  

Also please post the actual code you ran.  The code you posted contains spelling mistakes.

Comment: `rewind(f)` kinds of emulates the C function which does the same thing. not very useful if you ask me since `f.seek(0)` is clear enough

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### I would try reading [this post](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm) on `tutorials point`.

The top of the article should help you out:

> **`fileObject.seek(offset[, whence])`**
>
> The method `seek()` sets the file's current position at `offset`. The `whence` argument is optional and defaults to 0, which means absolute file positioning; other values are: 1, which means *seek relative to the current position*, and 2, which means *seek relative to the file's end*.

So in your code this is called inside the function `rewind()`, which is called on this line:

```
rewind(current_file)
```

in which:

```
f.seek(0)
```

is called.

So what it does here in your code is move the current position in the file to the *start* (**index 0**). The use of this in the code is that on the previous lines, the entire file was just read, so the position is at the very end of the file. This means that for future things (such as calling `f.readline()`), you will be in the wrong place, whereas you want to be at the beginning - hence the `.seek(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

there is something change in your file if you change to
def rewind(f):
    f.seek(2)
you cannot see first two letter of your input_file..in TERMINAL
NOT IN ORIGINAL FILE

Comment: please provide the code you intend to change with a clear explanation, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv
def print_all (f):
    print(f.read())

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print(line_count, f.readline())

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

current_file = open(input_file)

print("First let's print the whole file:\n")
print_all(current_file)
print("Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.")

rewind(current_file)
print("Let's print three lines:")

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
current_line= current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)#Pay attention to how we pass in the current line number each time we run print_a_line.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].